# Trouble with Printer function JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

I am having trouble with the printing function in java while attempting to print to a receipt sheet. The connection is successful but every print seems to be off to the right side. Not too sure what I can do to adjust the text or format of the paper so that it'll print fully.

My code section for print(calc is a TextArea)

```
Printer printer = Printer.getDefaultPrinter();

    if (printer != null) 
    {
        String name = printer.getName();
        System.out.println("Default printer name: " + name);
    } 
    else 
    {
        System.out.println("No printers installed.");
    }   
    Paper page = PrintHelper.createPaper("3x10", 76.2, 254, Units.MM);  
    PageLayout pageLayout = printer.createPageLayout(page, PageOrientation.PORTRAIT, 0, 0, 0, 0);


    PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.createPrinterJob();
    if (job != null) {
      System.out.println(job.jobStatusProperty().asString());
      boolean printed = job.printPage(pageLayout, calc);
      if (printed) {
        job.endJob();
      } else {
        System.out.println("Printing failed.");
      }
    } else {
      System.out.println("Could not create a printer job.");
    }
```

With this code I am attempting to print out this TextArea.
And this is the results I am left with
[image: TextArea]

[image]

Comment: Just guessing, but this looks like a mechanical issue more than anything. Is the paper properly aligned to the printing head? Also, if you try different dimensions, do you get different results? Or are they always printed from this origin?

Comment: @Cawfree I am not too sure about the printer head being aligned( its a CITIZEN CT-S2000 and I am not too sure if alignment is possible with this printer). Also yes I do but the only change is the text shifts more to the right once printed or changing to landscape displays the whole text but defeats the purpose of a receipt.